# HTML 5 audio, detect "play" with no errors

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

The HTML 5 audio API is super easy, [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) tells it all. But I am failing to achieve the following: catch the error (if there was one) and do something else when there are NO errors!

You may think this is easy, and that I should attach event listeners to the "error" and "play" events. But know the following:

- The "error" event works only on the sub element "source", not the "audio" tag itself, this of course makes sense, since there could be more than one source.
- The "play" event triggers when the file starts playing for the first time and also when the file is paused and played again!
- The "play" event is triggered regardless of any errors!

What I am trying to do is simply set both the "error" / "play" events, but prevent the "play" whenever an error occurs.

```
var player = $('audio#player');

player.find('source').on('error', function(){
    alert('Cannot play this file!');
});

player.on('play', function(){
    setTheNextSongToPlay(' .... ');
});
```

Now, the "setTheNextSongToPlay" function is called whether there were any errors or not. How is that possible anyway ?! THE FILES WASN'T PLAYED!